# Renaming variables in C++

Tags: c++, variables

I want to know if a variable content can be used as variable name. Example below:

```
int a;
string b = "nombre";
```

I'm asking if "nombre" can replace "a" as variable name.

I'm trying to rename an object(like we rename files and folders).

Comment: Are you asking if `nombre` is a valid identifier? If so, it is. If not then I have no idea what you're asking for.

Comment: You cannot say things like: use the value of this variable as the name of a new variable. E.g.: use `nombre`, the value of string variable `b`, as the name of a new variable (of whatever type).

Comment: Is your question that... if somehow ```int a;``` can turn into ```int nombre;``` ?

Comment: Variables names exists only in source code. Once you compile it they are gone. The closest to what you are asking, probably, is a reference.

Comment: No, but you can use an associative container, like [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Bob__: See my answer.

Comment: You can not directly create a variable with a name based on the value of another variable, but you can achieve a similar effect with a map by associating integer (or other type) values with string keys. This, however, does _not_ allow you to _rename_ a variable  (remap it to another name) other than by removing it from the map and reinserting with a new key.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to be able to map strings to numeric values, you could create a map object:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> vars {
        { "nombre",      5 },
        { "otro_nombre", 3 },
    };
    std::cout << vars["nombre"] << '+' << vars["otro_nombre"] 
        << " = " << (vars["nombre"] + vars["otro_nombre"]);
}
```

This yields:

```
5+3 = 8
```

on the output stream. See it working on [<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/5K57Mv9T6).

Answer (score 3):

You can use references to create an alias for an already existing variables, if this is what you're looking for.

```
int a = 5;
int& nombre = a; //nombre is now an alias for a
```